Ensuring stability for the explicit Runge-Kutte-Legendre method
I have successfully implemented the explicit Runge-Kutta-Legendre(RKL) method with super-time stepping to some problems in finance based on the Black-Scholes PDE. I am in the process of applying the method to some new similar settings.
However, in my attempts to prove stability for my discretization scheme I realize there are some subtle issues I am not sure how to handle.
Actually, the same issues would also occur for the simple explicit Euler method.
Let us denote our unknown function by $u$. It depends on time and one or more spatial variables. We will suppress the arguments when they are not needed for readability.
We are given the values of a function $u$ at a time $t$ and want to evolve it forward in time to $t+ \tau$. When we discretize our spatial variable(s) we get the discretization matrix we call $M$. We get a system of the type
$$
\frac{d u}{d t} =M u(t) \\
$$
In the RKL setting we are constructing a polynomial $R_s(z)$ based on the Legendre polynomials such that we have
$$
u(t+\tau) =R_s(\tau M) \cdot u(t).
$$
My problem is the estimation of the norms of $M$ and $R_s(\tau M)$. More precisely, in many texts it is simply claimed that a parabolic PDE leads to an $M$ which is symmetric and negative semidefinite. From what I can see, this is simply not true in general without some extra conditions. The reason I care is that those properties are used in theorems about the stability of the system.
To make the problem a bit more concrete lets look at a standard example with the (time reversed) Black-Scholes PDE (yes, I know, in this case it is possible to avoid the problem by transforming it into the heat equation, but this is not possible in general):
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial S^2}+r S \frac{\partial u}{\partial S}-r u \\
& u(0, s)=f(s) \quad \forall s
\end{aligned}
$$
Let us say we use a uniform spatial grid $\{ s_i\}$ with $s_{i+1} - s_i = h$ and central differences to approximate our derivatives
$$
\begin{aligned}
u^{\prime}\left(s_j\right) & =\frac{u\left(s_{j+1}\right)-u\left(s_{j-1}\right)}{2 h} \\
u^{\prime \prime}\left(s_j\right) & =\frac{u\left(s_{j+1}\right)-2 \cdot u\left(s_j\right)+ u\left(s_{j-1}\right)}{h^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
If we had a PDE with only the second derivative term with a constant coefficient, that is, the standard heat equation, this would indeed lead to a negative semi-definite discretization matrix $M$.
However, when the coefficient depends on the spatial variable, as in the example, the matrix is no longer symmetric, even though it will be quite close depending on the size of $h$ if the coefficent function is continuous.
Also the first derivative approximation introduces non-symmetry in $M$ by its very construction.
Finally the negative semi-definiteness of $M$ can always be violated by the term $-ru$ if $r$ is chosen large and negative enough.
One question here is how to know if the matrix is negative semi-definite in practice.
Yes, I know there are criteria for this, but if you use this in production code this is a no go. You want to avoid costly computations, especially those that have to be done at every time step.
Or is this problem very unlikely to occur unless you deliberately try to make it fail?
My thoughts about how to handle the issues is that you can always force the matrix to become negative semidefinite by a regularization term, that is you define a new function $v(t,x) = u(t,x) \cdot \exp{(-\lambda t)}$ leading to the same PDE for $v$, but with an extra term $\lambda v$. This will have the effect of adding a multiple of the identity to the discretization matrix $M$.
Also, you can always make the contribution from the first derivative terms small compared to the second derivative term by making the spatial step $h$ small. The same goes for the no-derivative term $-ru$. So it will be mostly the properties of the part coming from the second order term that matters.
Even if the matrix $M$ is negative semidefinite, there is another issue concerning the spectral properties. 
We know we can diagonalize a symmetric negative semidefinite matrix.
When it is no longer symmetric, we don't really know if this is possible anymore. It would be enough for it to have a Jordan form over the reals, but the characteristic function might theoretically have complex roots.
The property we will loose as a consequence of the non-symmetry is that we might no longer have that the spectral radius of the matrix is equal to its norm. This in turn makes the spectral properties of $R_s(\tau M)$ problematic to estimate in terms of spectral properties of $M$. 
To make things concrete, if the matrix $M$ can be put in Jordan form over the reals, for example if it is diagonalizable then a sufficient condition for the stability of
\begin{equation}
u(t+\tau)=R_s(\tau M) \cdot u(t)
\end{equation}
is that
\begin{equation}
\left|R_s(\tau \lambda)\right| \leqslant 1 \text { for }|\lambda| \leqslant|\rho(M)|.
\end{equation}
This is easily proven, but I don't really see how to do it without assuming the matrix $M$ can be put in Jordan form. The problem that
$$
  Spec(P(M)) = P(Spec(M))
$$
is not true for a general matrix if we work in the real number field.
If anyone could shed some light on these issues I would be greatful.
Maybe I am missing something obvious or made an error. Maybe there are some piece of theory behind this I have missed?
Or maybe these complications are very hard to check in practice, but are a non-issue in real applications anyway?

On bounded domains, it is true that a uniformly elliptic operator $L$ w/Dirichlet BCs has a simple eigenvalue $\lambda_1\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $Re(\lambda) \geq \lambda_1$ for any other eigenvalue $\lambda$. Perhaps a result of this sort could lead to some estimates on the semigroup $e^{-tL}$ or its discretization? This is from Ch. 6.5 of Evans
